# Deselect Input Box on Return/Enter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently using a client-side input box* that filters search results based on text input automatically; with no dependency on server side functions, in this case the return/enter key, (which would just refresh the page) so I have disabled it using:

```
<script>
var submitHandler = function() {
// do stuff
return false;
}
</script>
```

This served it's initial purpose, however, upon hitting the return/enter key, (using the code above) the text field should be deselected as well, is there a way I can achieve this?

*source: http://www.redotheweb.com/2013/05/15/client-side-full-text-search-in-css.html

View: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oooxp5Lb/)

Edit: Added Fiddle ^

Comment: Hope my snippet is on target :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the below script above your form

```
<script>
function enter_detector(e) {
 // if enter key is pressed lose focus
if(e.which==13||e.keyCode==13){
    this.blur();
}
}
//add a listener for input box   document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup',enter_detector,false);

</script>
```

here is a snippet

```html
<!-- Data generated by Faker, see https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker -->
<ul class="contacts">
<!-- Add text to the data-index attribute to enable full-text search -->
<!-- Don't forget to lowercase it to make search case-insensitive -->
<li class="searchable" data-index="onabednarschamberger.frank@wuckert.com1-265-479-1196x714">
<dl>
<dt>First Name</dt><dd>Ona</dd>
<dt>Last Name</dt><dd>Bednar</dd>
<dt>Email</dt><dd>schamberger.frank@wuckert.com</dd>
<dt>Phone</dt><dd>1-265-479-1196x714</dd>
</dl>
</li>
<li class="searchable" data-index="newtoncronintorphy.dorothea@gmail.com(121)644-5577">
<dl>
<dt>First Name</dt><dd>Newton</dd>
<dt>Last Name</dt><dd>Cronin</dd>
<dt>Email</dt><dd>torphy.dorothea@gmail.com</dd>
<dt>Phone</dt><dd>(121)644-5577</dd>
</dl>
</li>
<!-- add as much data as you want -->
</ul>

<form onsubmit="return false" class="form-search">
    <input class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="search" id="search" type="text" onKey>
    
</form>
<script>
function enter_detector(e) {
// if enter key is pressed lose focus
if(e.which==13||e.keyCode==13){
 this.blur();
}
}
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('keyup',enter_detector,false);

</script>
<style id="search_style"></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchStyle = document.getElementById('search_style');
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', function() {
if (!this.value) {
searchStyle.innerHTML = "";
return;
}
// look ma, no indexOf!
searchStyle.innerHTML = ".searchable:not([data-index*=\"" + this.value.toLowerCase() + "\"]) { display: none; }";
// beware of css injections!
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using jQuery's `onkeypress` event instead?
Otherwise, use use `$(this).blur();` to deselect the input

EDIT: `this.blur();` works equally if you're averse to jQuery

Comment: It looks like OP isn't using jQuery, or at least its not tagged so maybe give an answer with plain JS.

Comment: You could equally use `.blur();` without jQuery [Example] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp)

Comment: I've attached a fiddle above with the code I'm currently using, if you could clarify where I would need to put the .blur(); function?

Comment: @Ghost repzero's answer addresses this